# Why does my ASPX page goes into dynamic preview when debugging Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have a web application in C# in Visual studio 2012, when im starting the application to debug it with internet explorer my aspx page goes into **Dynamic Preview ReadOnly**. I want to edit while debugging and this mode prevent me from doing it. Does anyone know why this is happening and how i can correct this problem. Thank You

Comment: You can edit aspx page in debugging mode...but for code behind you have to stop debugging

Comment: I want to debug/edit my javascript code in my aspx page. I know i can because in my other web application it works just fine. My aspx page doesnt go into "Dynamic" when debugging and i can edit on the fly and continue.